# Doxygen code sections are not properly formatted in pdf file

Tags: latex, doxygen

I have `mainpage.dox` file, which is used as an introduction page for Doxygen documentation. It contains code sections, like this:

```
/*! \mainpage My project
 *
 * \code{.cpp}
 * void some_function()
 * {
 *     // ...
 * }
 * \endcode
 *
 */
```

Such code blocks look nice, when converted to HTML format. However, if I use Latex to produce pdf file, code sections look really bad. Long lines are broken (i.e. not formatted as `<pre>`). When such section is copied to clipboard from pdf, lines are broken and whitespaces are not preserved.

How can I fix this to get properly formatted code sections in pdf file?

Doxygen version is 1.9.5. PDF generation is done using MiKTeX 22.10.

Example of bad pdf formatting:

```
 * \code{.cpp}
 * void some_function()
 * {
 *     // long long long long long long long long source code line
 * }
 * \endcode
```

In HTML file this function looks like this:

```
 void some_function()
 {
     // long long long long long long long long source code line
 }
```

When converted to pdf:

```
 void some_function()
 {
     // long long long long long long long long 
   source code line
 }
```

When copied from pdf to clipboard, and pasted to text editor:

```
void some_function()
{
// long long long long long long long long 
source code line
}
```

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? What do you mean with "look really bad" please show your result in the question. You speak of long lines but in the example I only see relatively short lines.

Answer (score 1):

Comments cannot contain images so I resort to an answer.

The current doxygen version is 1.9.5 but it doesn't look like it makes a difference in respect to this problem.

**Doxyfile**

```
QUIET = YES
```

**mainpage.dox**

```
/*! \mainpage My project
 *
 * \code{.cpp}
 * void some_function()
 * {
 *     // long long long long long long long long source code line
 * }
 * \endcode
 *
 */
```

1.9.5 Latex result

[image]

and a cut / paste gives:

```
void some_function()
{
// long long long long long long long long source code line
}
```

looks  quite OK to me.

Comment: Thanks. I can see one of my problems in your cut/paste result: whitespaces are not preserved. This means, code formatting is broken. When the same section is copied from HTML, code formatting is OK.

Comment: From your results I can see, that this is standard Doxygen+Latex behavior. I hope there is some solution to get pdf with the same quality as HTML.

Comment: The original LaTex code contains `\DoxyCodeLine{\ \ \ \ \textcolor{comment}{//\ long\ long\ long\ long\ long\ long\ long\ long\ source\ code\ line}}` and in the pdf the spaces are shown but indeed in the cut / paste the spaces at the beginning of the line are gone ( a small test gave that also inside a line multiple spaces vanish / are compressed  during cut / paste). Maybe you can create an issue in respect to this problem in the doxygen issue tracker.